# Unable to select values from users?

Tags: php

In my code, I have two files; connection.php, and test.php

This is my code for connection.php:

```
<?php
session_id();
session_start();
ob_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'induadmi_main', '$admiNiNd/U');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$User = $_SESSION['Username'];

$Admin = $_SESSION['Admin'];

if ($User) {
   $MyUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='SamDreadrage'");
   $myU = mysql_fetch_object($MyUser); 
   var_dump($myU);
   $UserExist = mysql_num_rows($MyUser);

    if ($UserExist == "0") {

        session_destroy();
        header("Location: /index.php");

    }
}
```

And this is for test.php:

```
<?php 
include "connection.php";
echo 'password', $myU->Password;
?>
```

test.php is only echoing "password", not echoing "password TestPassword" like it should. connection.php also includes working connections in which I have tested, and I made sure all the tables `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='SamDreadrage'` in phpMyAdmin works, so I don't see the problem.

test.php is printing errors as well, which are:

> Notice: Undefined index: Admin in
>   /home/induadmi/public_html/por/connection.php on line 10

> Notice: Undefined index: Username in
>   /home/induadmi/public_html/por/connection.php on line 11

> Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /home/induadmi/public_html/por/connection.php on
>   line 16 bool(false)

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/induadmi/public_html/por/connection.php on line 18

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/induadmi/public_html/por/test.php on line 4

Comment: You need error handling, then the issue will be clear.

Comment: Can you make sure you are entering the `if ($User) {` conditional branch? Can you echo out the `$User` variable after the statement `$User = $_SESSION['Username'];`? If you hardcode the `$User` variable to `1` does it work?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['Username'];` is not set, therefore you will get these notices and errors, the proper way to check would be:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
    $User = $_SESSION['Username'];  
    //$Admin = $_SESSION['Admin'];

    $MyUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='SamDreadrage'");
    $myU = mysql_fetch_object($MyUser); 
    var_dump($myU);
    $UserExist = mysql_num_rows($MyUser);

        if ($UserExist == "0") {
            session_destroy();
            header("Location: /index.php");
        }
}else{
    echo "session is null";
}
```